# Understanding load average vs. cpu usage

Tags: linux, operating-system, load

Okay, I'm very much a Windows user myself, so my knowledge of Linux-y type things is a bit limited.

However it was my general understanding that "Load Average" is an indication of how many processed are being run at any given time, on average over the last minute, five minutes and... fifteen minutes?

Anyway, I've been monitoring my server because we had a big opening and lots of people!

[image: See?]

I've been watching `top` and noticed something that seemed contrary to what I thought I knew.

If the load average is at 7, with 4 hyper-threaded processors, shouldn't that means that the CPU is working to about 7/8 capacity?

Why, then was it showing 50.0%id? How can it be idle half the time?

Comment: Maybe these will offer some help: http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29 and http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9001 .

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`top` shows CPU utilization for running processes while `load average` shows (since 1993) number of running processes plus number of processes in the uninterruptible state. Processes waiting for work do not consume CPU. As a result `top` CPU utilization is less that 7/8 * 100%.

Source: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you - I must have missed the notification for this question in my power Stack Overflowing! But +1 and Accepted for a very thorough answer. Thank you!

Comment: Even skwllsp has given a detailed answer but it is hard to understand by avg load vs no. of running processes. so to understand it there is simple formula that for a single cpu machine avg load 1 denotes to 100% cpu utilization...while fora 4 cpu machine avg load 4 denotes to 100% cpu uitlization, so avg load 1 for 4 cpu machine means 25% cpu utilization..